# c# string condition is not working here

Tags: c#

I have some email accounts in a if condition and making some simple decisions but this is not working here with me Please help me to find out the issue.Here is my code

```
 if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                if ((lblemail.Text.Equals("ali.saleem@shakarganj.com.pk")) || (lblemail.Text.Equals("altaf.saleem@shakarganj.com.pk")) || (lblemail.Text.Equals("anjum.saleem@shakarganj.com.pk")) || (lblemail.Text.Equals("ibrahim.cheema@shakarganj.com.pk")) || (lblemail.Text.Equals("malik.adeel@shakarganj.com.pk")))
                {
                    GridView2.Visible = true;
                    GridView1.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    GridView1.Visible = true;
                    GridView2.Visible = false;
                }
            }
```

here i want to make an easy and proper way to handle my requirements please help me

Comment: Define "not working". _What_ is not working? Should you be using a case insensitive test?

Comment: This staement is directly going to else part even my lblemail is equal to `malik.adeel@shakarganj.com.pk`

Comment: What are your requirements and what exactly isn't working here?

Comment: And you are sure that the case is the same in both cases? No extra whitespace anywhere? Using the same culture?

Comment: have you verified in the debugger that the value of lblemail.Text is actual what you expect?

Comment: I am Sure that lblemail is equal to one of the string in if condtion but this is not working thats why i posted on stack expecting some issue with my code

Comment: Funny how all the answers just randomly try to find a solution to an unclear problem. :) @user1505962 just post the content of lblemail!

Comment: Rest assured lblemail.Text is not equal to either of the strings you compare it to, there's no obvious bugs in .NETs string comparison (That's of course assuming that lblemail.Text is of type string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks right.  Maybe the problem is due to capitalisation or trimming?  Try this:

```
if ((lblemail.Text.ToLower().Trim().Equals("ali.saleem@shakarganj.com.pk")) || 
    (lblemail.Text.ToLower().Trim().Equals("altaf.saleem@shakarganj.com.pk")) ||    
    (lblemail.Text.ToLower().Trim().Equals("anjum.saleem@shakarganj.com.pk")) || 
    (lblemail.Text.ToLower().Trim().Equals("ibrahim.cheema@shakarganj.com.pk")) || 
    (lblemail.Text.ToLower().Trim().Equals("malik.adeel@shakarganj.com.pk")))
{
    GridView2.Visible = true;
    GridView1.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: you should use to uppe since some unicode characters behave -eh eh- weird as in you will change the character when using tolower (not only change the capitalization)

Comment: Actually he should use a StringComparer that ignores case such as StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.invariantcultureignorecase.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be "tbEmail"(or something like that) instead of "lblemail"? What is the value of the lblemail.Text?

Comment: I am Sure that lblemail is equal to one of the string in if condtion but this is not working thats why i posted on stack expecting some issue with my code

Comment: I just tought that you compares the text of the wrong control.

Comment: Honestly, i like that answer :) that are some nice observation skills.

Answer (score 1):

Make a `List<string>` of all the email addresses and perform the check like this:

```
List<string> emailAddresses = CreateList();
if(emailAddresses.Contains(lblemail.Text))
{
      // Whatever you need to do
}
else
{
      // do the other thing
}
```

Comment: While its a good idea to do that, i don't think thats the actual problem. But to be fair, i think noone really knows what the problem is right now :)

Comment: Maybe he doesn't know the email needs to be case sensitive?

Comment: what, you mean emailAddresses.Add("my@test.com")?